# Think Deeply About It

Tags: riddle, word

> Find me in water, I'm mostly grey.
>   At the Spanish South I am red.
>   Coming down from the sky, I'm a lizard,
>   And notably worn on the head.
>   I am a star with rays that are straight.
>   Near a crystal river lies my key.
>   On reflection, my style is emo.
>   A Caesar directed me.

**What am I?**
**Please explain each line in your answer.**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Find me in water, I'm mostly grey.

> mullet - a fish, the grey mullet is common

At the Spanish South I am red.

> red mullet - found in warm seas, notably the Mediterranean

Coming down from the sky, I'm a lizard,

> land mullet - a large lizard of the skink family, to land is to come down from above

And notably worn on the head.

> mullet - an embarrassing hair style, see Bono or Bowie

I am a star with rays that are straight.

> In heraldry a mullet is a star with straight-sided rays

Near a crystal river lies my key.

> Mullet key - a historic island near Crystal River, Florida.

On reflection, my style is emo.

> Tellum - a reverse mullet, short at the back, considered an emo style

A Caesar directed me.

> Mullet - an Australian film directed by David Caesar

Title: Think Deeply About It

> Sounds like mull (think deeply) over it

Comment: Yep, great work Tom! My intention for the second line was slightly different but this is close enough to get the checkmark. Spot on with everything else.

Comment: I'm guessing line 2 concerns [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Striped_red_mullet) since 'south' in Spanish is 'sur'...

Comment: @Stiv, that's it! I wouldn't have got this though did think of the Spanish south. What a fish:)

Comment: Irrelevant, but when I was young I tried to fish in a harbour in which you could plainly see the first answer, but they were never caught by the hook - well done them.

Comment: Damn, nicely done. The last line led me on a red-fish search through **Roman** Polanski films.